# difference kernel exception handling and programming language exception handling

Tags: exception

I don't understand how c++, java or others high level languages that support exception handling work???
I know that if I write an application will be run in user mode and if it rises an exception like zero division, the system call an interrupt routine in kernel mode or use my try/catch block???

Comment: your question is not clear! Can you add more details to explain the question again?

Comment: The operating system kernel does not handle such an exception.  It merely detects the processor trap and ensures that it is passed to userland.  By whatever mechanism appropriate to the OS, like signals on Unix and SEH on Windows.  It is then up to the language runtime to turn that into a language-specific exception.  Any half-decent book about operating system design will explain that btw.

Answer (score 0):

what I want to say is:
when I write simple code in c++ for example like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double divide(int a, int b)
{
   if( b == 0 )
   {
      throw "Division by zero condition!";
   }
   return (a/b);
}

int main ()
{
   int x = 50;
   int y = 0;
   double z = 0;

   try {
     z = divide(x, y);
     cout << z << endl;
   }catch (const char* msg) {
     cerr << msg << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

and compile it, I'm getting an software with inside an exception routine.
I mean, during execution code CPU will try to do x/y and will raise an exception. Now, in this case who handles this error:
1) process un user mode pass the workflow to an exception routine that I write
Or
2) System switch in kernel mode and throw a trap for running an interrupt routine.

I don't understand what is the specific steps that system like linux or windows use to solve an exception???